# How to exclude .svn folders with robocopy

Tags: windows, svn, robocopy

does anyone know how to exclude .svn folders with Robocopy?
I want to copy all folders but I want to prevent to copy the subversion folders that svn creates.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `/xd ".svn"` folder exclusion should help in your case.